What are the other shortcuts available for "powerdevil invokeShortcut"?
The following command turns off a screen when running KDE with Wayland:
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/org_kde_powerdevil invokeShortcut "Turn Off Screen"

I see that whenever I look it up. But why does it do that? What's /component/org_kde_powerdevil? What's invokeShortcut? And, apart from the instructions for this very specific actions, how would I have found out that one such shortcut is "Turn Off Screens"? Where is this documented? Are there other such shortcuts? What are they?
I understand that part of this is KDE's DBUS. No, I'm not completely familiar with it, but I don't mind learning.
I don't mind reading source files. I just don't know where to find this.
